# UITextField Strange Behaviour When Entering Text

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

Want to Search this Issue on `Google` But Do't Know What i need to write for find the exact reason So i am here.

**ISSUE**
Create `UITextField` using `Interface Builder` and Run the project and while i am entering any value using `iOS Keyboard` this is what happening and i am confuse.

This Happened in One Project and as i created new one everything working fine.

Very First Time When App Started on Simulator.

[image]

Then I Entered single character `G` using `iOS Keyboard`

[image]

Then I Entered Again single character `G` using `iOS Keyboard`

[image]

Again single character `G` using `iOS Keyboard`

[image]

Again single character `G` using `iOS Keyboard`

[image]

what is the up down up down going here its totally strange but facing this problem.

You can review the [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm1LwZe68ks)

Please if anyone know about it share.

thanks

Comment: trying it on simulator or device?

Comment: tried on both `Simulator` and `Device` .

Comment: might be uicommitanimation is missing some where in your code

Comment: Please Explain Something ?

Comment: any code u have added to this uitextfield?

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of IB properties of it ?

Comment: @KumarKl No `IBOutlet` used only Drag and Drop `UITextField` using Interface builder and Run the Project only in one and another new project working fine. :)

Comment: @AhmedZ. No Code I added `UITextField` using Interface Builder

Comment: how about the superView of it .. if all fine, then it might be a bug.

Comment: It's unlikely to be an IOS bug but may be a "feechure".  You need to reproduce the behavior in a minimal app and post the code here.

Comment: Did you customise the font, size of font etc in IB?

Comment: @Yes Sure i will try to reproduce

Comment: I Di't use `IBOutlet` and yes i changed the font

Comment: Guys i Also Added `Youtube` Video Link as what issue i am facing. [please review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm1LwZe68ks)

Comment: whats the behaviour if you set the font back to the default value? Is the font you used a provided font in iOS or a custom one you added? I have seen a lot of problems with fonts that were originally intended for print use having there baselines way off when used in an app.

Comment: I Deleted the last one `UITextField` and created new as this one is fresh one as given by `UIKit`

Comment: Should I submit this issue to `Apple` with my `iOS project` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. Didn't have this in a previous release of my app 2 weeks ago.

I've found that the issue is coming from presenting a view controller embedded in a navigation controller with a translucent navigation bar.

I set opaque bar in the simulated metrics of the navigation controller I was presenting and no more issue with UITextField.

On my case at least, everything were resolved at the moment I set opaque bar for top bar in simulated metrics in InterfaceBuilder for my UINavigationController which embed a UIViewController I've wanted to present modally

Hope it will be the same for you as well.

Comment: +1 Yes if i set `opaque bar` on my `UINavigationViewController` Everything Work fine But I do't want to use it as i need `Top Bar` == `None` is there any solution related to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem just arrived here, and I reached this post via Google.
In my case, the UITextField was added in a xib, in a view controller presented modally, and I needed the navigationbar to remain translucent.

So the only workaround I found was to remove the outlet from XIB, and add it programmatically in viewDidLoad method.

That did the trick.

Comment: Yeah that is what i tried after `Ramzog` answer and thanks for posting this as an answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was when UITextField was added as first element of UI.
I worked with StoryBoard, so I put another element (UIButton) to first position and problem disappeared.

[image] 
   
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the solution is this: 
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

taken from here:

[Text in UITextField moves up after editing (center while editing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674566/text-in-uitextfield-moves-up-after-editing-center-while-editing)