# Extjs animateUnderline example

Tags: extjs

i am trying to animate my textField in my project with Extjs but it doesn't work

here a peace of my code:

```
 {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Try KeyDown',
            emptyText: 'Press Enter/Return here...',
            name: 'email',
            animateUnderline : true
                },
```

Comment: May you provide fiddle sample?

Comment: Check out this thread for the answers - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096578/uitextfield-text-jumps-when-animating-width-constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096578/uitextfield-text-jumps-when-animating-width-constraint)