# UITextField text shift to the left by 1px when edited

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield

In a right-aligned textfield, when it is edited, the text shift 1px to the left compared to the placeholder text's position. This doesn't happen on the simulator, only on a device (iPad in this case). Is this a known bug? Is there a way to fix to it?

There was a similar bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351340/using-a-custom-font-in-a-uitextfield-causes-it-to-shift-slightly-when-accessed) but I am not using custom font, just a System font.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced this before and I think its actually an iOS bug. Anyway apple provides two methods you can override in UITextField. Hope it helps.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)placeholderRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
```